# the pip model is not installed in python

Tags: python

I have tried several ways to get the pip module but recently I realized that the pip module is not installed when installing python and the folder where this module is supposed to be is empty.
What I can do?

Comment: can you show the contents of installed python directory?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to install pip directly! They're explained pretty well in pip's documentation:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

But I'd probably first try downloading the get-pip script from:
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

And running it using the command line in the folder containing the file:

> py get-pip.py

or

> python get-pip.py